# Firebase Cloud Messaging existing service worker

Tags: polymer, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I am trying to add the firebase-messaging-sw.js to my application, but I am already using a service-worker.js.

Can I just add the code to that and point FCM to service-worker.js, or how shoud I approach this?

Comment: Good to know that the current SW is from the polymer set.